# why i get a "?" in my angular2 url when i use a http post rest api

Tags: symfony, angular, formbuilder

hello i'm new in Angular , i'm trying to send to my backend(Symfony2.8) a Subject , Email and Message . when i route the the ***localhost:4200/contact*** , i get no error , no excption and the nothing happend , the URL becomes ***localhost:4200/contact?*** . here is my component,service and html file: (BTW i used this method to add and object to the database and it works normally)

```js
export class ContactComponent  {
contactForm: any;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public router: Router ,private cService: ContactService) { 
   
   this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'subject': ['', Validators.required],
      'email' : ['', Validators.required],
      'msg': ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

sendMessage() 
 {
     // console.log(this.contactForm.value.subject,this.contactForm.value.email,this.contactForm.value.msg);
    this.cService.sendMsg(this.contactForm.value.subject,this.contactForm.value.email,
           this.contactForm.value.msg)
                     .subscribe(
                       response => {
                        
                         alert("Thanks for contacting us");
                       },
                       error => {
                        alert(error);
                       }
                     );
```

```js
export class ContactService {
  
  url:string = '/web/contactus';
  constructor (private http: Http) {

  }
  sendMsg(subject: string,email: string, msg: string): Observable<any> {
    
let body = JSON.stringify({
      subject,
     email,
      msg
    } || null);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 console.log(body);
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                    .map(res => res.json().data)
                    .do(data => console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || null ))))
                    .catch(this.handleError);

  }

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (submit)="sendMessage()">
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Subject</label>
                        <input class="form-control" formControlName="subject"  placeholder="Subject"/>
                        <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.subject.valid">required</span>
                       
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input class="form-control" formControlName="email"  placeholder="Email"/>
                        <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.email.valid">required</span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label >Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="msg"  rows="6"></textarea>
                    <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.msg.valid">required</span>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">Post Message</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: you don't `return false`, neither `event.preventDefault` in your submit callback (`sendMessage`) or there is an error during its execution, so the form is posted via default method (GET), the page is reloaded and as none of your input has a `name` attribute, the queryString is empty.

Comment: try to do something like that `sendMessage(){ try{/*your current code*/}catch(e)[console.error(e);}return false;}` and see what happens.

Comment: i fixed it by  removing this line `.do(data => console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || null ))))`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is throwing some exception. In console click on the preserve log and then try the same. You may see some exceptions